# Magento ajax form does not post data

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, forms

Magento AJAX form does not post any data. Also does not show any error / success message.

I used form in **Popup**

In Console it shows **302 Found**

**My form**

```
<div style="display:none">

    <div id="myDivID">
        <div class="popup-wrap">
        <div class="popup-txt-01"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_1.png');?>"></div>
        <div class="popup-txt-02"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_2.png');?>"></div>
          <form class="my-form" name="myForm" id="proxelle">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="only-text" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" required="true" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here" required="true" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input type="submit" name="Go">
            <div class="popup-txt-03"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_3.png');?>"></div>
            <span id="formLoader" style="display:none;">Loss</span>
        </form>
        <div id="formSuccess" style="display:none;">Super</div>
    </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**Ajax Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var formId = 'proxelle';
    var myForm = new VarienForm(formId, true);
    var postUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('proxelle/index/addme') ?>';

    function doAjax() {
        if (myForm.validator.validate()) {
            new Ajax.Updater(
                { success:'formSuccess' }, postUrl, {
                    method:'post',
                    asynchronous:true,
                    evalScripts:false,
                    onComplete:function(request, json) {
                        Element.hide(formId);
                        Element.show('formSuccess');
                    },
                    onLoading:function(request, json){
                        Element.show('formLoader');
                    },
                    parameters: $(formId).serialize(true),
                }
            );
        }
    }

    new Event.observe(formId, 'submit', function(e){
        e.stop();
        doAjax();
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

**Popup Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("a#fancyBoxLink").fancybox({
        'href'   : '#myDivID',
        'titleShow'  : false,
        'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
        'openEffect'    : 'elastic',
        'closeEffect'   : 'elastic',
        'maxWidth'  : 800,
        'maxHeight' : 600,
        'fitToView' : false,
        'width'     : '70%',
        'height'        : '70%',
        'autoSize'  : false,
        'closeClick'    : false
    });

    $("#only-text").on('keyup', function(e) {
    var val = $(this).val();
   if (val.match(/[^a-zA-Z]/g)) {
       $(this).val(val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g,' '));
   }
});
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Any console error are display? Have you checked your controller action are working?

Comment: it shows 302 not post any data if i use without ajax it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved mine like this

```
var data =  jQuery(".fancybox-skin #proxelle").serialize(true);
```

then in parameters

```
 parameters: data,
```

Since fancy box creates a copy of your form, the ids are also duplicated... just get the one inside fancybox

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div style="display:none">

      <div id="myDivID">
          <div class="popup-wrap">
          <div class="popup-txt-01"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_1.png');?>"></div>
          <div class="popup-txt-02"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_2.png');?>"></div>
          <form id="proxelle" method="post" action="javascript:submitForm();">
              <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
              <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" class="required-entry" autocomplete="off"/>
              <input type="email" name="email" id='email' placeholder="Enter Your Email Id Here"  class="required-entry" autocomplete="off"/>
              <input type="submit"  title="<?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?>" >
              <div class="popup-txt-03"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/proxelle/txt_3.png');?>"></div>
              <span id="formLoader" style="display:none;">Loss</span>
          </form>
          <div id="formSuccess" style="display:none;">Super</div>
      </div>
      </div>

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     //<![CDATA[
       function submitForm() {
       var url = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('proxelle/index/addme') ?>';

       var formData = new VarienForm('proxelle', true);
       var parameters = {
         fname: jQuery('input[name=fname]').val(),
         email: escape(jQuery('input[name=email]').val()),
         formkey: escape(jQuery('input[name=form_key]').val()),
        };
       $('formLoader').show();
       var request = new Ajax.Request(
         url,
         {
           method: 'post',
           onSuccess: function (transport) {
             var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
             if (data.error) {
                 $('formLoader').hide();
                 alert('Submit Error');
             }
             else {
                   $('formLoader').hide();
                   $('proxelle').hide();
                   $('formSuccess').show();
             }
           },
           parameters: parameters,
         }
       );
       }
       //]]>

  </script>
```

Please try this code